# SQL Query taking a long time to execute -- several NOT IN clauses

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following SQL query.

```
SELECT *
FROM   contacts
WHERE  contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                      FROM   campaign_extraction_history
                      WHERE  sf_oms_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505-2-2020'
                             AND sf_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505'
                             AND ( current_date - creation_date :: DATE ) <
                                 1
                             AND channel = 'BOTH'
                             AND ( Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'
                                    OR Upper(status) = 'LAUNCHED'
                                    OR Upper(status) = 'CONFIRMED' ))
   AND contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                          FROM   campaign_extraction_history
                          WHERE  creation_date :: DATE = current_date
                                 AND channel = 'BOTH'
                                 AND ( Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'
                                        OR Upper(status) = 'LAUNCHED'
                                        OR Upper(status) = 'CONFIRMED' )
                          GROUP  BY contact_id
                          HAVING Count(*) > 10)
   AND contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                          FROM   campaign_extraction_history
                          WHERE  sf_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505'
                                 AND channel = 'BOTH'
                                 AND ( Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'
                                        OR Upper(status) = 'LAUNCHED'
                                        OR Upper(status) = 'CONFIRMED' )
                          GROUP  BY contact_id
                          HAVING Count(*) >= 3)
```

Query plan:

```
XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=28.77..12938626.48 rows=2075740 width=801)
     ->  XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=20.32..4672671.27 rows=2075740 width=801)
         ->  XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=9.12..4166713.31 rows=2075740 width=801)
             ->  XN Hash (cost=9.12..9.12 rows=1 width=402)
                 ->  XN Subquery Scan "IN_subquery" (cost=9.10..9.12 rows=1 width=402)
                     ->  XN HashAggregate (cost=9.10..9.11 rows=1 width=40)
                         ->  XN Seq Scan on campaign_extraction_history (cost=0.00..9.10 rows=1 width=40)
         ->  XN Hash (cost=11.20..11.20 rows=1 width=40)
             ->  XN Seq Scan on campaign_extraction_history (cost=0.00..11.20 rows=1 width=40)
     ->  XN Hash (cost=8.44..8.44 rows=2 width=402)
         ->  XN Subquery Scan "IN_subquery" (cost=8.41..8.44 rows=2 width=402)
             ->  XN HashAggregate (cost=8.41..8.42 rows=2 width=40)
                 ->  XN Seq Scan on campaign_extraction_history (cost=0.00..8.40 rows=2 width=40)
```

This is taking long time to execute. Is there a way to rewrite this to optimized it?

Comment: You could instead try to look into indexing strategies to make the exists clauses execute faster.

Comment: I am using Redshift, so there are no indexes needed.

Comment: The statement "no indexes needed" goes against the premise of your question, which is about making your query run faster.

Comment: Try to merge the subqueries into one.

Comment: @jarlh - I don't know how to merge the subqueries as they have different group by clause. :(

Comment: `Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'`  sql string comparisons are normally case-insensitive by default.  Do you really need the `Upper` ?  Or could you use an interger statusId column instead of strings.

Comment: Could you please add the `EXPLAIN PLAN` to your question. It will show where most time is being spent.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Added query plan for the above query.

Comment: @BuhBuh the tables are read-only for me. I cannot change or use integer columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query plan shows that the highest costs are related to the `NOT IN` subqueries:

```
N Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=28.77..12938626.48 rows=2075740 width=801)
     ->  XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=20.32..4672671.27 rows=2075740 width=801)
         ->  XN Hash NOT IN Join DS_BCAST_INNER (cost=9.12..4166713.31 rows=2075740 width=801)
             ->  XN Hash (cost=9.12..9.12 rows=1 width=402)
```

It is generally recommended to avoid `NOT IN` in queries, since they are inefficient. (For example, it needs to look through every returned result in the sub-select to know that something is NOT IN the list.) A `NOT IN` can sometimes be replaced by using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and checking for NULL values. (You'll see suggestions if you do some web searches on the topic.)

Also, casting fields (eg `Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'`) removes efficiency because the database needs to convert every value, which defeats the optimizations that the database can provide through the way data is stored. It is always better to compare raw values than computed values. So, it would be good if you can remove the `Upper()` functions.

Then there are the `DS_BCAST_INNER` references. From [Evaluating the query plan - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_data_redistribution.html):

> `DS_BCAST_INNER` and `DS_DIST_BOTH` are not good. Usually these redistributions occur because the tables are not joined on their distribution keys. If the fact table does not already have a distribution key, specify the joining column as the distribution key for both tables. If the fact table already has a distribution key on another column, you should evaluate whether changing the distribution key to collocate this join will improve overall performance. If changing the distribution key of the outer table is not an optimal choice, you can achieve collocation by specifying `DISTSTYLE ALL` for the inner table.

One of the great features of Amazon Redshift is the ability to distribute data amongst nodes and slices using the Distribution Key (`DISTKEY`). Typically, a table should be distributed based on the field that is most used in JOINS. This is because data related to that field (eg `contact_id`) would be co-located on the same node or slice, avoiding the need to move data between nodes. However, `DS_BCAST_INNER` indicates that the *"A copy of the entire inner table is broadcast to all the compute nodes."* This is not good for large tables.

Thus, you could possibly improve the query performance by improving the `DISTKEY` and `SORTKEY` used on each of the tables. Other than that, you would need to avoid the inefficient `NOT IN` queries and sub-selects.

If the query is run often, you might benefit by **populating temporary tables that contain the data used by the sub-selects**. These temporary tables could be populated once per day, and then the query could consult those tables rather than having to Query, Group and Having the data for every query.

Answer (score -1):

Could you test the following SQL query, please?

**Note:** Please, check the data type in the DECLARE line.

```
DECLARE @ContactID TABLE (contact_id INT, 
                           sf_oms_campaign_id VARCHAR(100), 
                           sf_campaign_id VARCHAR(100), 
                           current_date DATETIME, 
                           creation_date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @ContactID
select contact_id, sf_oms_campaign_id, sf_campaign_id, current_date, creation_date
from campaign_extraction_history
where (Upper(status) = 'EXTRACTED'
OR Upper(status) = 'LAUNCHED'
OR Upper(status) = 'CONFIRMED')
AND channel = 'BOTH'

SELECT *
FROM   contacts
WHERE  contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                      FROM   @ContactID
                      WHERE  sf_oms_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505-2-2020'
                             AND sf_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505'
                             AND ( current_date - creation_date :: DATE ) < 1
   AND contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                          FROM   @ContactID
                          WHERE  creation_date :: DATE = current_date
                          GROUP  BY contact_id
                          HAVING Count(*) > 10)
   AND contact_id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id
                          FROM   @ContactID
                          WHERE  sf_campaign_id = 'ABC-013505'
                          GROUP  BY contact_id
                          HAVING Count(*) >= 3)
```

Comment: Declare does not work. It is giving this error SQL Error [500310] [42601]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "@" 
Position: 9;

Comment: DECLARE works successfully in SQL. Maybe you should specific all the information when you create the post and not edit it later with new info and tags.